# Restore files after using 'Discard' tool in Xcode

Tags: xcode

For the last 2 weeks i have been working on an app. Today i was doing some bug fixes for it and ended up creating more bugs than i fixed. So I decided the smart thing to do would be to simple revert to the last saved file in Xcode, I used this but it did not revert my file back enough (Maybe there was an autosave?).
So when i looked on the bar at the right of the screen i was this:
http://gyazo.com/ad2b4e02d60dcf774b6d665ecb873d33

Somehow i missed the words 'Source Control' and ignored the fact that i hadn't saved the source or anything, I clicked the 'Discard' button thinking that would revert me to a saved version.

Now i have lost my entire .m file and all the coding for the app. I have checked my trash and its not there, also since the project is saved in dropbox the file is updated straight away so I could not retrieve it there.

Stupidly I have not taken a backup.

Is there a way for my to retrieve my files? if so please comment or answer any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out luck is on my side!!!

For anyone else having this problem and has also saved their project into DropBox:
Find the file you discarded and is now reset, right click on it and you can access previous versions over the last few days! (If you don't see the 'Previous Versions' tab try going onto the in browser version of DropBox (On the website) and right click on the file from there!